Adjusting Collection View Height Dynamically in a Table Cell based on Datasource Cell Count
I'm currently working on a chatbot project where I have a table view with dynamic content, including cells containing collection views. These collection views have varying numbers of cells based on the data.
My challenge is to dynamically adjust the height of the collection view within the table cell according to the number of cells it contains. Essentially, I want the collection view's height to expand or contract based on the number of items in it.
Is there a way to achieve this programmatically within iOS development, possibly using Auto Layout or other techniques? Any insights, suggestions, or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!
import UIKit

class CategoryPick: UITableViewCell {
    

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var categoriesArray : [CategoriesType] = [
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Hotel", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Restarunt", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Natural LandMarks", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Museum", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Parks", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Hotel", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Restarunt", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Natural LandMarks", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Museum", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Parks", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Hotel", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Restarunt", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Natural LandMarks", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Museum", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot"),
        CategoriesType(categoryName: "Parks", categoryImage: "awards_chatbot")
        ]
    var selectedCategories: [CategoriesType] = []
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
                    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10 // Adjust as needed
                    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10 // Adjust as needed
           
                }
        super.awakeFromNib()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CategoryCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCollectionCell")
    }

}
extension CategoryPick: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categoriesArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionCell
        
        let category = categoriesArray[indexPath.item]
        cell.labelText.text = category.categoryName
        cell.ImgIcon.image = UIImage(named: category.categoryImage)
        cell.bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 14.5
        
        // Check if category is selected
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = selectedCategories.contains(category) ? UIColor.gray : UIColor(red: 33.0/255.0, green: 135.0/255.0, blue:199.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let category = categoriesArray[indexPath.item]
        
        if let index = selectedCategories.firstIndex(of: category) {
            selectedCategories.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            selectedCategories.append(category)
        }
        
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let category = categoriesArray[indexPath.item]
        let labelText = category.categoryName
        
        let labelSize = (labelText as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])
        
        // Add padding as needed
        let cellWidth = labelSize.width +  20.0
        let cellHeight = labelSize.height +  20.0
        
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    }


}

struct CategoriesType: Equatable {
    let categoryName: String
    let categoryImage : String

    static func ==(lhs: CategoriesType, rhs: CategoriesType) -> Bool {
        return lhs.categoryName == rhs.categoryName && lhs.categoryImage == rhs.categoryImage
    }
}



Need solution for autolayout collection view height resize based on the content by storyboard
